# VB.NET filecopy program Error : System.NullReferenceException in FolderBrowserDialog1

Tags: vb.net, nullreferenceexception

I am  trying to make a program which copies files from one folder to another and I am also using a progress bar to see what files are copying. When I am running this program I am getting an error on folderbrowserdialog1. The error is System.NullReferenceException. When I am running the program I am able to open the application but when i select the button it gives me an error.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim my As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess

    Dim directoryTargetLocation As String 'Selected file path
    Dim Destinydirectory As String 'Selected dest directory path

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim FolderBrowserDialog1 As Object = Nothing
    FolderBrowserDialog1.Description = "Select directory" **// Gettig error in this Line**
    With FolderBrowserDialog1
        If .ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            directoryTargetLocation = .SelectedPath
            TextBox1.Text = directoryTargetLocation.ToString
            Button2.Enabled = True

        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    FolderBrowserDialog2.Description = "Select destiny directory"
    With FolderBrowserDialog2
        If .ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Destinydirectory = .SelectedPath
            TextBox2.Text = Destinydirectory.ToString
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Remove(TextBox2.Text.Length - 1) & 
     TextBox1.Text.Substring(TextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf("\"))
            Button3.Enabled = True

        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Set an variable to `Nothing` (null) and then try to use a property of that variable and _**of course**_ you'll get a `NullReferenceExcepton`. This is really basic stuff here.

Answer (score 1):

You have not created a FolderBrowserDialog1 object.

**Edit**

You were close!

What you need is:

```
Dim FolderBrowserDialog1 As New FolderBrowserDialog
```

This creates a new FolderBrowserDialog object.

What you have is:

```
Dim FolderBrowserDialog1 As Object = Nothing
```

Which creates a new generic object name FolderBrowserDialog1, and explicitly sets it to be "nothing"

This means it does not have any of the properties or methods you were referencing, so you get the error.

Comment: After creating an object for folderbrowserdialog it's still giving me an error

Answer (score 1):

You declared FolderBrowserDialog1 as an object.

What you want to do is to declare it as a FolderBrowserDialog.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim FolderBrowserDialog1 As New FolderBrowserDialog
    FolderBrowserDialog1.Description = "Select directory"
    With FolderBrowserDialog1
        If .ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            directoryTargetLocation = .SelectedPath
            TextBox1.Text = directoryTargetLocation.ToString
            Button2.Enabled = True

        End If
    End With
End Sub
```